# RecyclerView search filter getting wrong position after filtering result

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

Hello friend please help me i am using Recylerview and implemented searchfilter but problem is that after searching the item in recylerview when i click on item   it always return 0 position of the item i want actual position of list item please me help here is my code how get actual position recylerview after searching item in recylerview

here is my code

```
package bible.swordof.God;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> books;
    private ArrayList<String> bookid;
    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb = null;
    BookRecyclerAdopter bookRecyclerAdopter;

//life is awesome

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        setData();
        RecyclerView bookanme = findViewById(R.id.list);
        bookanme.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    bookRecyclerAdopter = new BookRecyclerAdopter(this, books);

        bookanme.setAdapter(bookRecyclerAdopter);



        /*    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_listview, books, bookid);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/







        /* listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 int booknumber=position;
                 String  bookname=bookid.get(position);





                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+bookname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             *//*   Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Chapters.class);
                intent.putExtra("booknumber",booknumber);

                intent.putExtra("bookname",bookname);

                startActivity(intent);*//*



            }
        });
    }

*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search_voice_btn:
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device Don't Support Speech Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


                    Toast.makeText(this, "" + result.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(myActionMenuItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment;
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.home) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.favoruite) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Favourite.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void setData() {


        books = new ArrayList<>();
        bookid = new ArrayList<>();

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select b,n from key_english", new String[]{});


        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    books.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    bookid.add(cursor.getString(0));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newtext) {

        String userinput = newtext.toLowerCase();
        List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name : books) {

            if (name.toLowerCase().contains(userinput)) {

                newlist.add(name);


            }


        }

        bookRecyclerAdopter.updatelist(newlist);
        return true;

    }

}




package bible.swordof.God;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookRecyclerAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookRecyclerAdopter.Booksholder>{

    private List<String> bookname;

Context context;

    public BookRecyclerAdopter(Context context,List<String> bookname) {
        this.bookname = bookname;
        this.context=context;

    }



    public class Booksholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView bookname;

        public Booksholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            bookname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Booksholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, viewGroup, false);


        return new Booksholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Booksholder booksholder, final int i) {
        booksholder.bookname.setText(bookname.get(i));

        //get first letter of each String item
        String firstLetter = String.valueOf(bookname.get(i).charAt(0));




        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
        // generate random color
        int color = generator.getColor(bookname.get(i));

        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(firstLetter, color); // radius in px



        booksholder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);




    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookname.size();
    }

public  void  updatelist(List<String>newlist){
        bookname=new ArrayList<>();
        bookname.addAll(newlist);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: Where exactly in the code are you filtering? Your click listener looks empty. It will be easier if you can add some comment or separate out the code where you think is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @GB take look my code carefully its easy to understand

Comment: register your click listener in onBindViewHolder()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to maintain a separate list of bookname. Let's call it `filteredBookname`. Initially set it as `bookname`.

```
public class BookRecyclerAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookRecyclerAdopter.Booksholder>{

    private List<String> bookname;
    private List<String> filteredBookname;

Context context;

    public BookRecyclerAdopter(Context context,List<String> bookname) {
        this.bookname = bookname;
        this.filteredBookname = bookname
        this.context=context;

    }
...
// other pieces of code.
```

and instead of using `bookname` to populate `RecyclerView` items, use `filteredBookname`

and your update list method will be,

```
public  void  updatelist(List<String>newlist){
        filteredBookname=new ArrayList<>();
        filteredBookname.addAll(newlist);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Using the above approach, you can always find the proper position of your item in the original list `bookname`

Comment: thanks for replying but after changing its not filter the result

Comment: have you changed your code in `onBindViewHolder` method as well? Replace all references of `bookname` with `filteredBookname` in that method.

Comment: i am new will you edit full code for me if you don't mind

Comment: I would rather prefer you asking me silly question than me spoon-feed you the whole solution. Can you tell me specifically which part of my instruction did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are picking the wrong list, pick your data from filtered adapter list/model.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Books booksdata= (Books)adapterName.bookname.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+booksdata.bookname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Chapters.class);
            intent.putExtra("booknumber",booksdata.booknumber);
            intent.putExtra("bookname",booksdata.bookname);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        holder.cardView_title.setOnClickListener {
        when (holder.tv_number.text) {
            "1" -> {
                (context as Activity).startActivity(Intent(context, Ma1::class.java))
            }
            "2" -> {
                (context as Activity).startActivity(Intent(context, Ma2::class.java))
            }
            "3" -> {
                (context as Activity).startActivity(Intent(context, Ma3::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
```